# qt design issue

Tags: python, user-interface, qt

i'm trying to design interface like this one
http://www.softpedia.com/screenshots/FlashFXP_2.png

i'm using the QT design and programming with python
well on the left it's a treeWidget
but what is on the right side ? as everytime i change the cursor on the tree
all widgets replace...

thanks :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [QStackedWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qstackedwidget.html). You insert several widgets which correspond to the **pages**. Changing the active item in tree should switch the active widget/page inside the stacked widget.